# Add a jar dependency to a project, manually in IntelliJ, when Maven, Gradle, SBT, aren't here

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, dependency-management

I'm learning *Spark* from a book.
It provides me many source files as examples, but without any `pom.xml`, *Gradle*, for building directives.

At opening/loading time, *IntelliJ* automatically discovered that *Java* and *Scala* SDK were missing, and it asked me which ones I was willing to select. What I did, and now I have them set:

[image]

But I need to add two other dependencies to specify where *Spark* jars are (`spark-core` and `spark-sql` especially), else, the IDE complains against `spark` environment variable missing it the examples:

[image]

I need to do this by the mean of *IntelliJ* itself, without the help of *Maven*, *Gradle*, *SBT*.
(like in the old times where those tools didn't existed, or in very old projects)

Where should I go, in *IntelliJ*, to add the missing jars dependencies for my project?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency

Comment: Yes, it should be that.